# How to specify a editor to open crontab file? "export EDITOR=vi" does not work

Tags: linux, vim

I'm using Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5, and I want to set the vim editor to edit the crontab file.

If I run `echo $EDITOR`, I get vim. But when I run  `crontab -e`, I get different editor.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Very probable that your `VISUAL` environment variable is set to something else. Try:

```
export VISUAL=vi
```

Comment: setting variable `export VISUAL=vim` (`setenv VISUAL "vim"` for tcsh shell) it works GREATLY!!

Comment: @lwpro2: If `VISUAL` is not set the `EDITOR` variable is used. But `VISUAL` has precedence over `EDITOR`.

Comment: If the crontab is managed by several persons with one user, I recommend to do this in a subshell, so the default editor stays in place.

Comment: Any ideas why the file is different when opened in vi instead of nano?

Answer (score 81):

To quote the man:

> The -e option is used to edit the current crontab using the editor specified by the VISUAL or  EDITOR  environment  variables

Most often if you run `crontab -e` from X, you have `VISUAL` set; that's what is used. Try this:

`VISUAL=vi crontab -e`

It just worked for me :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Indeed I am running my terminal from X.

Comment: Best option if your are running crontab -e with sudo :) `sudo VISUAL=vi crontab -e`

Answer (score 45):

If the above methods don't work (as they didn't work on my Ubuntu 13.04 installation) try:

There are a number of alternative ways:

**1) Run select-editor**

```
select-editor
```

**2) Manually edit the file: `~/.selected_editor` specifying your preferred editor.  With this option you can specify editor parameters.**

```
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/emacs -nw"
```

**3) You can specify on the fly on the commandline with:**

```
env VISUAL="emacs -nw" crontab -e
```

Comment: I was by mistake setting default editor to `nano` when opening crontab first time. Then I had to use `sudo select-editor` to get it to work. A tip if only `select-editor` doesn't work

Comment: You shouldn't use "sudo" for your personal configuration.  It might break things forcing you to stay at elevated operation for normal computer use.  The sudo (elevated command) is for working with systemwide features outside your personal area (~user area).

Answer (score 6):

I think you might need to use the full path:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

Comment: The trap is that `VISUAL` is checked first. So a perfectly sound advice like yours works well for an SSH session and mysteriously fails on a desktop box.

Comment: I tried exporting while assigning as described, but it didn't work. By assigning first and then exporting it worked for me, like so: EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi; export EDITOR . Using SunOS under SSH here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use below command to open it in VIM editor.

```
export VISUAL=vim; crontab -e
```

Note: Please make sure VIM editor is installed on your server.

Answer (score 4):

`export EDITOR=vim` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

It wasn't working for me. I run crontab with sudo, so I switched to root, did the above suggestions, and crontab would open in vim, but it still wouldn't from my user account. Finally I ran `sudo select-editor` from the user account and that did the trick.

Comment: If you have to run sudo to configure your user environment, that signifying problems that you should address.  You have run sudo on your personal space and lost permission to files that should be owned by you.  You can check your space by running: `find ~/ -mount ! -user $(whoami)`.  You can correct the problem by running: `sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/`.

Comment: @L.D.James You were right, thank you. As it turns out it was just the .select_editor file that was owned by root.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me :

```
EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim"
export EDITOR
```

Add this to ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc to enable this for current user.