# Why Crontab throwing segmentation fault?

Tags: segmentation-fault, cron

I had a job which was running like every 2 hours. Today I wanted to change the timings. When I put `crontab -e` I got this error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
                                crontab: "/usr/bin/sensible-editor" exited with status 139
          nikhil@nikhil-HP-Pavilion-13-Notebook-PC:~$
```

I did a search and found that its some kind of bug. I am unable to resolve this bug.

Comment: It would suggest to me that the editor that you have defined as your default editor `/usr/bin/sensible-editor` is the problem. Can you run the editor from the command-line? You could try to change to, e.g. `vi` just to see if it gets rid of the segfault, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952467/how-to-specify-a-editor-to-open-crontab-file-export-editor-vi-does-not-work) question

Comment: @SiHa I tried using nano but same problem

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I have encountered the same thing without being able to overcome.  Have tested with `vi` so far. And `env` tells `EDITOR=/bin/vi`

Comment: I don't remember. But then soon after my system crashed and when I tried again it worked on the fresh system

Comment: I have about 10 jobs scheduled, does this error come when two programs overlap in execution?
What is the reason exactly.